# Filling holes and gaps in shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, holes, gap

I converted a RBG to a raster then created a vector based on the values I wanted. The file looks good but there are some 'gaps' between the polygons. I tried the delete holes function but it doesn't seem to work for this. Ideas on how to fill the holes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tecnically, most of these gaps are not "holes": the only "hole" in the screenshot region is the one in the light-green feature on the left.
All others are just areas which are not covered by any polygon.

Holes inside feature can be removed with the `Delete hole` tool which can be found under `Processing`-> `Toolbox:`

[image]

For the gaps, instead, you need to define which criteria to adopt.

For example: are the void "pixels" going to be filled in dark green or light green? based on what?

Given the specific input raster data, I would probably start with

`Raster`->`Analysis`->`Proximity (Raster Distance)`

possibly with these parameters:

[image]

(change "987" with a meaningful default value, like the one used for dark-green)